# Getting microphone volume while recording

Tags: android, record, volume, playback, microphone

I'm using the simple app shown in the Android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html) to play around with recording and playing audio. Just to add a small feature, I want to get the volume of the microphone while it's recording to move a bar like how the voice recognition will fill the microphone while you are speaking into it. I looked around online, but no one seems to have a definitive answer, could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: Did you find any workaround for getting microphone volume?

Comment: I never ended up getting this working the way I originally intended. This was quite a long time ago and I don't really remember what I ended up doing; probably scrapped the idea I was going for.

Answer (score 0):

i think there is no specific volume for mic. when you are recording that takes media volume as mic volume.

Comment: Well I've heard there isn't a very direct way of getting the volume of the microphone, but there are some workarounds that might work for what I'm trying to do.